# How to send delete request with custom header using Spring's WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor, reactor-netty

I want to send an http delete request with custom header.

I tried to do this with Spring's WebClient, with following code:

```
@Test
public void validateDeleteCouldCarryHeader() {
    WebClient.create("https://jira.spring.io/")
            .delete()
            .header("X-FOO", "BAR")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Map.class)
            .block();
}
```

I am expecting something like:

```
DELETE / HTTP/1.1
X-FOO: BAR 
...
content-length: 0
```

But, the actual request made is:

```
DELETE / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.0.RELEASE
host: jira.spring.io
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 0
```

Did I miss some thing to include the custom header ***X-FOO*** ?

Update 1: I upgraded reactor-netty to 0.7.3.RELEASE,

And the missing header is still missing:

```
DELETE / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.3.RELEASE
host: jira.spring.io
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 0
2018-12-28 22:32:32.813 DEBUG 12064 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient       : [id: 0x2c6a9cea, L:/172.17.1.131:54532 - R:jira.spring.io/35.199.60.33:443] WRITE: 138B
        +-------------------------------------------------+
        |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 44 45 4c 45 54 45 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e |DELETE / HTTP/1.|
|00000010| 31 0d 0a 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 52 |1..user-agent: R|
|00000020| 65 61 63 74 6f 72 4e 65 74 74 79 2f 30 2e 37 2e |eactorNetty/0.7.|
|00000030| 33 2e 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45 0d 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a |3.RELEASE..host:|
|00000040| 20 6a 69 72 61 2e 73 70 72 69 6e 67 2e 69 6f 0d | jira.spring.io.|
|00000050| 0a 61 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 61 63 |.accept: */*..ac|
|00000060| 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 67 |cept-encoding: g|
|00000070| 7a 69 70 0d 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 6c 65 6e |zip..content-len|
|00000080| 67 74 68 3a 20 30 0d 0a 0d 0a                   |gth: 0....      |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Update 2: I found there's a reactor's BOM (Bismuth-RELEASE) imported in my pom, after removed that BOM, Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE included the custom header I want.

```
DELETE / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.7.9.RELEASE
host: jira.spring.io
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip
X-FOO: BAR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactor Netty 0.7.0.RELEASE is quite old now, and you should upgrade to a newer version.

I've tried to reproduce this and couldn't.

Setting the log level of `reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient` to "DEBUG" shows this:

```
[reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0x69202b84, L:/192.168.0.28:60880 - R:jira.spring.io/35.199.60.33:443] WRITE: 150B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 44 45 4c 45 54 45 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e |DELETE / HTTP/1.|
|00000010| 31 0d 0a 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 52 |1..user-agent: R|
|00000020| 65 61 63 74 6f 72 4e 65 74 74 79 2f 30 2e 37 2e |eactorNetty/0.7.|
|00000030| 30 2e 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45 0d 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a |0.RELEASE..host:|
|00000040| 20 6a 69 72 61 2e 73 70 72 69 6e 67 2e 69 6f 0d | jira.spring.io.|
|00000050| 0a 61 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 61 63 |.accept: */*..ac|
|00000060| 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 67 |cept-encoding: g|
|00000070| 7a 69 70 0d 0a 58 2d 46 4f 4f 3a 20 42 41 52 0d |zip..X-FOO: BAR.|
|00000080| 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a |.content-length:|
|00000090| 20 30 0d 0a 0d 0a                               | 0....          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

So the client is indeed sending those headers. Maybe there's something wrong with the way you're capturing the outgoing request information?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try update the reactor netty first.

And, I did have set DEBUG log level to print the netty debug log, and that confirms the custom header is missing.

Comment: I ran the exact same code snippet. Which Spring Framework are you using?

Comment: I was using spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.5.RELEASE, and I am upgrading to 2.1.1.RELEASE right now.

Comment: After upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent, this is solved. So I think I should accept this answer.

Comment: there is something wrong in your build then, since Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE depends on reactor Bismuth-SR11, which itself depends on reactor netty 0.7.9.RELEASE. Something must be wrong with the dependency management. Are you overriding the reactor netty version?

Comment: Yes, when I upgrading Spring Boot, I found my pom have a reactor Bismuth-RELEASE BOM imported.

If I removed that, Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, it might have been an incompatibility between Spring Framework and Reactor Netty. Thanks for checking!